# Spring Security-Error creating bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Tags: spring, security

I am trying basic spring security set up. I am using 3.1.0.RELEASE
I have in the spring security xml as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider>
<security:user-service>
<security:user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER,      ROLE_ADMIN" />
<security:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When I access the start page , I get the following exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce ption: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL.

Can any one help me?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)

Comment: **************************web xml***********     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. One hint: instead of adding commands, you can edit the question, this would make it more readable.

Answer (score 11):

The actual cause of the problem seems to be that spring-security 3.1.0 pulls in older versions of spring which create a silent conflict. In my case spring-security-3.1.0.RELEASE pulled in spring-aop, spring-jdbc, spring-tx and spring-expression 3.0.6 but I was using spring 3.1.0.RELEASE. After adding these dependencies explicitly the problem went away.

Comment: this is the correct diagnosis, add dep management for aop/jdbc/etc and it will fix it:

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.xml` looks like you missed the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`

Your `web.xml` shoul have this elements:

```
<!-- or in your case /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My-Web-SpringProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter-mapping>
    <!-- do not change this name! -->
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<!-- it is configured by the parameter contextConfigLocation in the begining -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My-Web-SpringProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*To be honest, this is a Spring 3.0 configuration, but I think it is the same for 3.1*